# Is there an enforced time limit between questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, rate-limiting, time-limit

I was browsing the site money.stackexchange, and had two related but still distinct questions I wanted to ask. I posted the first, but after writing the second and attempting to post, I encountered this:

[image]

Now on Math.Stackexchange I've often posted 2-3 distinct questions in a go (then doing my own responsbility of answering as many on the site as I can while waiting for responses).

Has a 5-minute cap also made its way to Math.SE? Or is that a feature unique to money.se (and perhaps others).

On the latter note, is it discouraged to post multiple (but nothing obnoxious just 2 or 3 max with all being very distinct) questions simultaneously? I feel as long as users responsibly answer questions to ensure the site doesn't get flooded they should be allowed to do this, but perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: You might have a look at [The Complete Rate Limiting Guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) on the main meta to see whether you find there something about this. On this meta.math.SE I found only these posts mentioning 20 minutes limit for users with reputation under 125: [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9162/how-often-can-i-ask-a-question/9164#9164) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19663/concerns-about-time-in-between-posting).

Answer (score 9):

According to   [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide), users with < 125 reputation can ask a question once every 20 minutes (90 minutes on Stack Overflow).

It's quite possible that the guide is outdated and the interval is now 5 minutes rather than 20. In any case, the difference between your experience on Money and Math can be attributed to the difference of your reputation on these sites.

Comment: It certainly does appear that that's outdated - I just saw a (brand new) user post four questions in less than 20 minutes.